# Sybase ASE monitoring tool of choice

Tags: sybase, redhat, sybase-ase

I have inherited an Sybase ASE 16 database server and my initial task consist on deploy some Key Performance Indicators to monitor the RDBMS instance performance.

I have 3 tools available in the company:

- Cacti
- Nagios
- Ganglia

And I'd like to have easy to read, nice-looking performance graphs like this:

[image: Query Response Time Example]

I'm starting to look for information about configurations to be made to achieve this.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with SybaseASE since last 7 years, I can tell that the newer versions of sybaseASE relies on MDA tables (just like SQLServer DMVs). The tools out there for SybaseASE monitoring are pretty expensive.

I my company, I have build reporting on the top of MDA tables. The prettiness of the graphs you have linked comes at cost.

As a cheap alternative (It is a modest 6.99 U$K per core ) would be to use [ASEProfiler](https://andrewmeph.wordpress.com/2016/09/13/ase-profiler-ase-monitoring-in-the-age-of-big-guns/) or DBACockpit (sybase 16 and up).

As for the configuration settings, each environment is different, so the configuration settings will be different. Start with the common ones and monitor them **`sp_monitorconfig 'all', null, 'full'`** .. esp the reuse count should never be more than 0.

- Data cache
- procedure cache
- max memory
- partition the data cache
- have multiple data cache e.g. 2K, 8K or 16K.
- Online engines (sybase 15.7 and up)
- max lava operators

All above settings can be tuned using `sp_sysmon`.

Comment: Kin, thanks for the time to respond my question. Could you post one of your querys againts the MDA tables you comment? Maybe could be just enough to query some metrics againts that MDA's and hand craft some results against RRDtool to get some graphs into Cacti!